# How to design extendable error codes?

Tags: java, python, design-patterns, error-handling, software-design

**UPDATE:
The error codes here is not such a return value of a function. Actually I am not discussing using exception or error codes for error handling. I am trying to figure out, using what pattern to  organize errors. 
What I am really doing is like error codes showing on Windows blue screen. Back to the very old time, when your Windows crash you can get an error code on blue screen, using that code you can figure out what's going on by looking up MS's document.
In my system, there are many plugins contributed by different people that may not know each other. If I allow them to define their error codes. It's mostly like error code of two plugins may conflict**.

================================================================================================

I want to design an extendable error codes system that allows plugins to define their own error codes.
The basic idea is:

1. system has a range of reserved error codes
2. plugin can select a range that not used by system, then creates its error codes in that range. However, the problem is plugins don't know each other(because plugins may be written by different people and installed into system by user's preference). so their error codes range may conflict.

Is there any good practice for this requirement? I google a lot but to my surprise, there are very few  articles talking about designing error codes in production software. Most posts are focus on exception vs error code.

And, is there any good pattern for showing error in product that user could figure out what's going on?
My basic idea is to show user an error which has error code, descriptions, details. And user could click the error code then I would show him the proper solution

Comment: You shouldn't design a system to use error codes unless there you have some sort of constraint. Error codes don't have the richness of exceptions and generally promote bad design in other areas,

Comment: why is this tagged java and python ... in python its all exceptions ...

Comment: No point, so many different programs use so many different libraries. A average user may not even understand Types in programming. A good programmer will keep code well documented and very well tested but will also have backups for when errors are unavoidable if the user input is wrong, its all in the hands of the programmer

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what the plugin system you are building does...

Shouldn't it be the responsibility of the plugin to provide this information to the host application?  Why not make the result of executing an operation on the plugin include these items?  This way your host application doesn't care about plugin specific implementation details, just that something was OK or not...

```
const int OP_SUCCESS = 0;

// structure returned for plugin ops
struct OperationResponse {
    int code; // any other value than OP_SUCCESS is plugin-defined
    string message; // operation optional message, even if success
    // other fields
};
```

So every call to a plugin does:

```
OperationResponse r = plugin.DoOperation();

if (r.code != OP_SUCCESS) {
    // do something with r.message and other fields
}
```

Comment: Still, if the error code is "prefixed" with the plugin provider and plugin name, e.g. a namespace you won't really conflict.  For example: error com.foo.plugins.XYZ.0039 would mean foo.com's XYZ plugin error #0039.

Answer (score 0):

For every exception your app throws you insert it into a db, your error code is the id for that record, that's what the user sees. Obviously same exception gets the same id. The plugin information you need is stored in the DB

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't resolve conflicts. Say plugin A uses code 10 for xxx exception, and plugin B doesn't know A because they are written by different people, B also uses 10 for yyy exception.

Comment: They won't. A and B will just throw an exception and the outer most layer of your app will have an exception handling mechanism that will insert it into a db if is not already there, and will return the record id (error code) to the user. If A and B happen to thrown exactly the same exception, with identical stacktrace then it IS the same error you have to solve. Usually two pieces of code will throw different exceptions / stacktraces. So, neither A or B or any other plugin will have to "document" they codes, they will be inserted into this DB and that's it

Comment: Thanks for explanation. but it doesn't work for me. for example, A and B both throw IOException, where A's reason is cannot write to a file while B has reason of network connection refused. In this case the error code is the same but they are really different errors to user. @OscarRyz

Comment: The stacktrace will be very very different, even the error message will be very different, hence they will use different ids. The problem with the error code is they are not scalable but if you insists just assign a 3 - 4 letter code to the plugin and let them use any error code they want. So if plugin A is for "Awesome Advanced whateever" assign them the plugin code AAW ...they code range will be AAW-001 to AAW-999 ( or 9999 or 99999 ) while plugin B can be BAR-864

Comment: I'm interested on how would you handle this at the end, so if you can ( and I'm sure it would benefit someone else in the future ) add your own answer on how you did it at the end. :)

Comment: thanks, I will update this thread when I finally adopt a solution in my system, though it may take some time @OscarRyz